# Getting null value for variable on using regular expression extractor for Json response

Tags: jmeter

I tested regular expression using view result tree, it returns correct data(30 match results).
i used reference name in regular expression extractor as regexid.
Regular expression i used is \d{7}
${regexid} has value equals null.
cross checked in debug sampler. it has below info
regexid=null
regexid_g=0
regexid_g0=6104546

Why regexid has null value, when there were 30 matches for this regular expression
[image]

Template value - $1$
and for match number i tried using 1,2,0,-1 but i still get null value

Comment: is it possible to share jmx file masking any sensitive data?